# Adding a google pixel to a Contribution Page

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute, google

What is the best way to integrate google Adwords to CiviCRM? Specifically we want to add a pixel to the contributions page, without messing with civi's functionality.

Thanks in advance!
Jaime

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

- Set up a sidebar in your WordPress theme that only appears on contribution pages that contains the pixel.  I know how to do this in Drupal using Blocks; I don't know how to do it in WordPress off the top of my head, but I'm sure it's doable.
- If you are or have access to a coder, you can write a CiviCRM extension to do this.  [I've written one for Facebook Conversion Pixels](https://github.com/PalanteJon/civicrm-facebook-conversion-pixel) for successful donations.  My guess is you could modify this pretty easily, or hire someone to do so.